# Start Activity from one package to another package

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have different activities in different packages,

Suppose I have two package 
->com.pack1
->com.pack2

I have a Activity in pack1 and want to call another Activity in pack2. How will I do that, using intents shows

`21:19:10.405: W/System.err(7578): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

[image: This is how my packages look]

Comment: post your manifest.xml, that is where the problem is.  Once you do I (or somebody) can show you to have many package declarations.

Comment: @edthethird Manifest file: http://j.mp/MsDzyA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally activities are private to their package. You can't start an activity in another package unless that activity is explicitly "exported" (ie: made known to other applications). Add this to you manifest for FlipAgain2Activity in com.pack2:

```
android:exported="true"
```

Comment: Implemented your above code, after that the Activity2 package name changes to  `06-28 22:18:31.749: W/System.err(8680): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.flipagain2/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
`

Comment: What if I change the `FlipAgain2Activity` package name to existing package name of `CaptureActivity`, I think that will solve the problem, but how can I change as the package already exists

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. You need to "export" the activity you are trying to start (ie: CaptureActivity) so that it can be seen by the FilAgain2Activity.

Comment: Are you trying to start the CaptureActivity using explicit intent (ie: specifying the class) or by implicit Intent (ie: specifying the ACTION in the Intent). Please post the code you are using to start this activity.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(
       "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity");
     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.flipagain2",
       "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"));
     startActivity(intent);`

Comment: OK. The problem is that you are setting the ACTION in the Intent (correctly) and **also** setting the component (that's bad). Remove the `intent.setComponent()` call and you should be good. The manifest you posted has an intent filter for that ACTION so it should work.

Comment: Sir, I have removed `intent.setComponent()` and now it is again taking wrong path `com.flipagain2/com.flipagain2.CaptureActivity` 

My project structure: http://cl.ly/HiWF

Comment: You need to fix the manifest for flipagain2. The declaration for the CaptureActivity should look like this: `<activity name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"` instead of `<activity name=".CaptureActivity"`

Comment: Changing that gives this error: http://f.cl.ly/items/3Z3b0w0M2G1g1P0w2s2L/loggy.txt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13180/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-samrat-mazumdar)

Comment: The issue was with strings.xml file in values folder

Answer (score 2):

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.mypkg.mystff","com.mypkg.mystuff.MyClass"));
```

The other answers are correct as well.  This, however, will work from anywhere in the device.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Add this to the  part of your xml

Comment: After using the above code, it doesn't shows any error nor warning but it doesn't even loads the activity, it shows this `06-28 21:39:30.389: I/WindowManager(190): createSurface Window{41b19380 Toast paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
`

Comment: Did you replace the packages with your packages?  Did you call `startActivity(i)`?

Comment: Oops! Sorry forgot that, now after doing that it is showing same error as above. My Manifest.xml file: http://j.mp/MsDzyA

Comment: If I include that I will have two LAUNCHER activities

Answer (score 1):

Please read the error.

"Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml". pakage do not make problem For go one Activity another Activity. Check you AndroidManifest.xml that activity are declear in AndroidManifest.

I think problem happen for this reason.

thanks.

Comment: Sir, from `FlipAgain2Activity` to `CaptureActivity`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you declare the activity in you **AndroidManifest.xml** or you can't use it.

Example:

```
    <activity 
        android:name="com.yourpackage.YourActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
     >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Implementing above shows `06-28 21:52:33.694: E/AndroidRuntime(8324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.flipagain2/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f090039
`

Answer (score 1):

OK, so there are two parts that work together to define the `Activity` location.  First, is the `package` attribute-- below it is `"com.flipagain2"

Also there is the `android:name` attribute, which, for example, is `.FlipAgain2Activity.`
So, this means when Android looks for your activity, it is looking at

`com.flipagain2.FlipAgain2Activity.`  Make sense?  Just combine those two things.

So, you want Activities in two packages.

Change the second (one that isn't working" to look like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.package2.CaptureActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Do you see what I changed?  Leave the first `Activity` declaration the same, but change the second `android:name=` to match the fully qualified name including the package.  Using this approach, every Activity can be in a different package.

Comment: Done above, but it is loading wrong package. It is loading `com.flipagain2/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}`. It  should only load `com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity`

Comment: What if change the `FlipAgain2Activity` package name to existing package name of `CaptureActivity`, I think that will solve the problem, but how can I change as the package already exists

Comment: ahhh ok, change both `android:name=` to equal the fully qualified name, and don't put anything in the `package`.  I forgot, it will automatically append `package` the beginning of `android:name`

Comment: getting closer!  that's a different problem.  It looks like CaptureActivity.java:755, you are calling `setText` on a `TextView`-- and you are trying to set a number as a text.  so, instead of `setText(1)`, try `setText(""+1) -- This will set the text as a String, and not as an Int-- if you setText as an int, it will look for that int in R and fail as it is.

Comment: The issue was with strings.xml file in values folder, it's solved now and thanks for helping me